# return true; NOT routing to link

Tags: javascript, html

Cannot get my submit button to route to this html page upon validation...
culprit -----------------> return true; window.location.href= "Info/index.html";

```
function validate()
      {

         if( document.myLogIn.user_id.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Please provide your Customer ID!" );
            document.myLogIn.user_id.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

         if( document.myLogIn.password.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Please provide your Password!" );
            document.myLogIn.password.focus() ;
            return false;
         }
          return true; window.location.href= "Info/index.html";
      }
```

Comment: Did you try placing `window.location.href= "Info/index.html"`; before the return statement?

Comment: Yes sadly didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Reason: Code unreachable.

In your code:

```
window.location.href= "Info/index.html";
```

won't be executed because you already set the 'return' statement.

Don't know exactly what your up to but you can set your code like this instead:

```
window.location.href= "Info/index.html";
return true;
```

So your redirection will be executed before you set the return value to true.

Best of luck!

Comment: No such luck - running a validate function on a customer ID and if the field is filled in when they click submit they are re-routed to another page...

Comment: window.location.href= "Info/index.html";
return false;

Comment: to be exact, the return statement is actually not needed since once the  
window.location.href is executed, the code below it will be neglected somehow. therefore, 'return false' is optional.